# How to integrate VLC media player in my Delphi app

Tags: delphi, vlc, libvlc

Currently I am playing with FFMPEG to add video playback in my 64bit app developed in Delphi.

I read somewhere that VLC medial player is more powerful and has more features.

Is there any control or library that I can use to play videos in my 64bit app at a given location on form.

One peculiar thing that I require is to be able to skip a few frames as per users configuration during playback.

I did try out VLC but the code sample provided on VLC web site works only for 32bit app and not for 64bit apps.

Here is the code to initialize VLC:

````
var
  sL: TStringList;
  VLCPath: string;
begin
  // load vlc library
  VLCPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  VLCPath := VLCPath + 'vlc';
  //VLCPath := VLCPath + 'vlc64';

  vlclib := LoadVLCLibrary(VLCPath);
  if vlclib = 0 then begin
    Showmessage('Load vlc library failed');
    Exit;
  end;
  // sL will contains list of functions fail to load
  sL := TStringList.Create;
  if not LoadVLCFunctions(vlclib, sL) then begin
    Showmessage('Some functions failed to load : ' + #13#10 + sL.Text);
    FreeLibrary(vlclib);
    sL.Free;
    Exit;
  end;
  sL.Free;```

Code for playing video:
procedure TfrmMain.btnPlayClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  VidFile: PAnsiChar;
begin
  VidFile := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'videos\Happy.mp4'));

  // create new vlc instance
  vlcInstance := libvlc_new(0, nil);
  // create new vlc media from file
  vlcMedia := libvlc_media_new_path(vlcInstance, VidFile);

  // if you want to play from network, use libvlc_media_new_location instead
  // vlcMedia := libvlc_media_new_location(vlcInstance, 'udp://@225.2.1.27:5127');

  // create new vlc media player
  vlcMediaPlayer := libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(vlcMedia);

  // now no need the vlc media, free it
  libvlc_media_release(vlcMedia);

  // play video in a TPanel, if not call this routine, vlc media will open a new window
  libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(vlcMediaPlayer, Pointer(pnlMain.Handle));

  // play media
  libvlc_media_player_play(vlcMediaPlayer);
end; ``` 

TIA
````

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/

Comment: See also https://prog.olsztyn.pl/paslibvlc/.